# How to check if GRUB is password protected or not?

Tags: debian, filesystems, grub

Is there any command to check whether GRUB boot loader is password protected or not?
What is the file path? where it stores this information specially on Debian OS.

Comment: Do you see `password` line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`? That is indication of grub being password protected

Comment: As of now I don't have any machine with GRUB password protected, if it possible could you please provide sample example for same?

Comment: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.dk/2008/09/how-to-setup-boot-password-grub.html .. just use your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead of `menu.lst`. Be Careful!!!